# Merge DataFrame with multi index columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I downloaded data from different sources in dataframes and would like to merge them in one final DataFrame. Let's illustarte it with the following example:

**dataframe 1** (already multi indexed columns)

```
index    stockA        stockB      ...
        O  L  H  C    O  L  H  C
1/1/19  10 15 20 17  35 30 39 37
2/1/19  ...          ...
...
```

**dataframe 2** (non multi indexed columns)

```
index    stockA  stockB     
1/1/19    1.5     3.2 
2/1/19    ...     ...
...
```

I would like to merge both dataframe and giving a column name to data in dataframe2 . Index Date might be not the same in both dataframe, So i might need to do an inner merge.

**Expected outputs** (multi indexed columns)

```
index    stockA                 stockB             ...
        O  L  H  C new_col    O  L  H  C  new_col
1/1/19  10 15 20 17 1.5       35 30 39 37  3.2
2/1/19       ...                     ...
...
```

Comment: Can you add expected output for `1)` and `2)` ? Why `inner merge` with sample data is necessary? Maybe is necessary change data to [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially for `2)`

Comment: Hi, I removed `2)` as I figured it out. I'd need `inner merge` because dates might not match between dataframes. But I can overcome this by reslicing the new dataframe with intersected dates between dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df1)
       stockA             stockB            
            O   L   H   C      O   L   H   C
1/1/19     10  15  20  17     35  30  39  37
2/1/19     12  13  26  27     31  50  29  17

print (df2)
        stockA  stockB
2/1/19     1.5     3.2
3/1/19     1.2     6.2
```

Convert index in both `index` to `datetime`s if necessary:

```
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index, format='%d/%m/%y')
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index, format='%d/%m/%y')
```

Get same values in both indices by [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
idx = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
print (idx)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Create `MultiIndex` in [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) in `df2`:

```
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.columns, ['new']])
print (df2)
           stockA stockB
              new    new
2019-01-02    1.5    3.2
2019-01-03    1.2    6.2
```

Filter both DataFrames by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), join together by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and last sorting `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df1.loc[idx].join(df2.loc[idx]).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
print (df)
           stockA                  stockB                 
                C   H   L   O  new      C   H   L   O  new
2019-01-02     27  26  13  12  1.5     17  29  50  31  3.2
```